# Query Performance with and without foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, query-performance

I'm doing a comparative study of NoSQL (Cassandra, HBase) and RDBMS (MySQL) databases performance.

In relational model , I have a data model with 10 tables. Due to relationships one has 6 foreign keys and one 4 foreign keys.

For example, when I run the following query:

```html
SELECT unique_carrier
FROM 
(
    SELECT C.unique_carrier,
           COUNT(V.IDflight) FligthDelaysNumber, 
           SUM(V.DepDelay) TotalDelaysTime
    FROM carriers C
    INNER JOIN airplane A
       ON A.Unique_carrier = C.unique_carrier 
    INNER JOIN flight V
       ON V.TailNumber = A.TailNumber
    WHERE V.DepDelay > 0              
    GROUP BY C.unique_carrier
) delays
ORDER BY FligthDelaysNumber DESC, TotalDelaysTime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

when I run the query with EXPLAIN I get the following results:

Without foreign keys:
[image]

With foreign keys:
[image]

Query performance is much better when the database does not have foreign keys than when has it. Should not it be the opposite?

How can I do to optimize queries in the case when have defined foreign keys?

Comment: Foreign key has some overhead, but that overhead doesn't outweigh the benefits of referential integrity they can provide. Indexing fields in foreign key relationship in child and parent tables helps mitigate the overhead. Are the fields participating in joins and queries indexed -- e.g. airplane.unique_carrier, flight.tailnumber, flight.depdelay, etc.? Is the field in parent table primary key?

Comment: unique_carrier is primary key of carriers table and foreign key of airplane table. TailNumber is primary key of airplane table and foreign key of flight table. DepDelay is only a field of flight table...

Comment: The next step would be to see query plan using EXPLAIN with and without FKs. That will give us an idea of what path DB is taking when FKs are present and when they aren't present. Can you post the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT unique_carrier...LIMIT 1;` with and without FKs?

Comment: It is perhaps unrealistic to compare against just one database. Mysql has to evaluate the 10 indexes available on your table before deciding which one to use (or to not use any at all) that can take a bit of time. + the size of the data also matters. For small tables indexes don't really give a big performance boost. For very small tables the query optimizer might decide not to use the index at all!

Comment: ok I'll edit my question with these results...

Comment: You can't evaluate the two vastly different solutions like that. Are you evaluating the **lexer** or what? Once the query is lexed and execution plan is ready, then MySQL begins to utilize the hardware to retrieve the data. The step in which NoSQL wins is that their grammar is extremely simple, therefore the only, and only thing where NoSQL is actually quicker is lexing. It doesn't retrieve the data any faster. What you're essentially doing is measuring whether Earth is lighter when you lift the grain of sand and throw it in the air. You'll draw wrong conclusions from this benchmarks sadly.

Comment: My performance analysis is based on database volume (50 million records and 100 million records) and also multiple access to data...

Comment: Why include `A` in the query??